# Добавление точек после ввода двух цифр переводит курсор на начало строки. Почему?

Tags: android, kotlin

на скриншоте (gif) сама проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это часть кода:

```
            currentField.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                when (currentField.text.length) {
                    2 -> {
                        val curText = currentField.text.toString()
                        currentField.setText(curText + ".")
                    }

                    5 -> {
                        val curText = currentField.text.toString()
                        currentField.setText(curText + ".")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из-за `setText()`, оно бросает курсор в начало строки.

Варианты:

вместо `setText(curText + ".")` использовать `append(".")`

или к тому что есть добавить

```
currentField.setSelection(currentField.text.length)
```